# Retrieve the diff / original values of a CodeMirror merge.js

Tags: merge, codemirror

I am trying to retrieve both the original (may be modified as I am allowing it) as well as the data I am comparing to (which might also be modified).

The documentation doesn't explain how to do it, there is references to origLeft and origRight, but they seem to not work properly - one is NULL (left) and the other doesn't appear to contain the modified data.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<div id=editor></div>

<script>
var original = 'Original text';
var compareTo = 'Modified text';

hilight= true;
var target = document.getElementById("editor");

dv = CodeMirror.MergeView(target, {
    value: original ,
    origLeft: null,
    orig: compareTo ,
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: "text/html",
    highlightDifferences: hilight,
    lineWrapping : true,
  });
</script>
```

I tried doing dv.getValue(), dv.leftOriginal(), dv.rightOriginal(), etc. no luck

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `dv.rightOriginal().getValue()` and `dv.editor().getValue()` (for the edited content) are what you are looking for. (These methods, `leftOriginal`, `rightOriginal`, and `editor`, return CodeMirror instances.)

Comment: `dv.editor.getValue()` will fail with `Uncaught TypeError: Object function () { return this.edit; } has no method 'getValue'`. The correct variable is `dv.edit.getValue()`

Comment: I missed a set of parens in my answer (`editor` is a method). Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Why shouldn't we add to documents.